# How to get the file name of each of the connections (webpage)

Tags: c, multithreading, file, http, webserver

We are trying to write a multi-threaded web server but we don't know how to get the file name from each of the HTTP requests (web pages) to a simple server. We are also concerned about the size of each of these files as well. Any idea?

Here is our main for the server.c file:

```
     int main(int argc, char *argv[])
     {
        int listenfd, connfd, port, clientlen;
        struct sockaddr_in clientaddr;

        getargs(&port, argc, argv);

        listenfd = Open_listenfd(port);
        thread_pool_init();    

        for(;;){
                pthread_mutex_lock(&pool_lock);
                while(buf_count == request_limit)
                        pthread_cond_wait(&signal_worker, &pool_lock);
                clientlen = sizeof(clientaddr);
                connfd = Accept(listenfd, (SA *)&clientaddr, (socklen_t *) &clientlen);

        //get/parse html file name here 
        //get file size using stat

                put(connfd);

                pthread_cond_signal(&signal_worker);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&pool_lock);
        }
```

Our open_connection code in client.c which sends HTTP requests to the server.c file, looks like this :

```
void * open_connection( ){

        clientfd = Open_clientfd(host, port);

        clientSend(clientfd, filename);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        clientPrint(clientfd);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

        Close(clientfd);
        sem_post(&cond);
        return NULL;
}



 //Send an HTTP request for the specified file 

void clientSend(int fd, char *filename)
{
  char buf[MAXLINE];
  char hostname[MAXLINE];

  Gethostname(hostname, MAXLINE);

  //Form and send the HTTP request 
  sprintf(buf, "GET %s HTTP/1.1\n", filename);
  sprintf(buf, "%shost: %s\n\r\n", buf, hostname);
  Rio_writen(fd, buf, strlen(buf));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you receive the HTTP request you need to parse it to retrieve the name of the file requested and then send the file back to the client.

I post a simple code that can be used to handle HTTP request which I have used in one of my experiment. It is really simple, it does not take into account a lot of different characteristics of the HTTP protocol, basically it works only with GET request,  but it may be a good starting point.

The `recv_request` is a function that reads the request from the socket used to communicate with the client.

```
#define PORT                 80  
#define WEBROOT              "/var/www/localhost/htdocs/"

void handle_connection(int sockfd, struct sockaddr_in *client_addr_ptr) {
   unsigned char *ptr, request[REQUEST], resource[REQUEST];
   int fd, length;

   memset(request, 0,  REQUEST); 
   memset(resource, 0,  REQUEST); 
   length = recv_request(sockfd, request);

   printf("Got request from %s:%d lenght: %d  \n", inet_ntoa(client_addr_ptr->sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr_ptr->sin_port),length);
   puts("--------------------------------\n"); 
   printf("%.*s", 500, request);
   puts("--------------------------------"); 


   ptr = strstr(request, " HTTP/"); // search for valid looking request
   if(ptr == NULL) { // then this isn't valid HTTP
      printf(" NOT HTTP!\n");
   } else {
      *ptr = 0; // terminate the buffer at the end of the URL
      ptr = NULL; // set ptr to NULL (used to flag for an invalid request)
      if(strncmp(request, "GET ", 4) == 0)  // get request
         ptr = request+4; // ptr is the URL
      if(strncmp(request, "HEAD ", 5) == 0) // head request
         ptr = request+5; // ptr is the URL

      if(ptr == NULL) { // then this is not a recognized request
         printf("\tUNKNOWN REQUEST!\n");
      } else { // valid request, with ptr pointing to the resource name
         if (ptr[strlen(ptr) - 1] == '/')  // for resources ending with '/'
            strcat(ptr, "index.html");     // add 'index.html' to the end
         strcpy(resource, WEBROOT);     // begin resource with web root path
         strcat(resource, ptr);         //  and join it with resource path
         fd = open(resource, O_RDONLY, 0); // try to open the file
         printf("Opening \'%s\'\t", resource);
         if(fd == -1) { // if file is not found
            printf(" 404 Not Found\n");
            send_string(sockfd, "HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND\r\n");
            send_string(sockfd, "Server: Tiny webserver\r\n\r\n");
            send_string(sockfd, "<html><head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>");
            send_string(sockfd, "<body><h1>URL not found</h1></body></html>\r\n");
         } else {      // otherwise, serve up the file
            printf(" 200 OK\n\n");
            send_string(sockfd, "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");
            send_string(sockfd, "Server: Tiny webserver\r\n\r\n");
            if(ptr == request + 4) { // then this is a GET request
               if( (length = get_file_size(fd)) == -1)
                  fatal("getting resource file size");
               if( (ptr = (unsigned char *) malloc(length)) == NULL)
                  fatal("allocating memory for reading resource");
               read(fd, ptr, length); // read the file into memory
               write(sockfd, ptr, length);  // send it to socket
               free(ptr); // free file memory
            }
            close(fd); // close the file
         } // end if block for file found/not found
      } // end if block for valid request
   } // end if block for valid HTTP
   shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_RDWR); // close the socket gracefully

   return; 
}
```

You should give a look at the [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/) library.